# How to register listener with CompositeItemProcessor

Tags: java, spring-batch

I have a composite item processor like below.

```
<bean id="myProcessors"
        class="org.springframework.batch.item.support.CompositeItemProcessor"
        scope="step">
        <property name="delegates">
            <util:list>
                <ref bean="processor1" />
                <ref bean="processor2" />
                <ref bean="processor3" />
                <ref bean="processor4" />
            </util:list>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

How do i register listener to it which gets execute after all the processors are complete and before writer gettes called? I want to transform the result object of processor4 to another object which writer can use to persist it.

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the `CompositeItemProcessor`, you should be able to register an `ItemProcessListener` normally and it will execute once around the whole composite since the framework doesn't have real knowledge of the underlying delegates.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to transform the result object of processor4 to another object which writer can use to persist it.

Why don't you simply add another processor to your composite that does this transformation? I don't believe you can modify the result object type with an `ItemProcessListener`.